# finite state machine transition table problem

Tags: computer-science, automata, finite-automata

I have the following question which im not able to do. I have done things with DFA/NFA's before but this is the first time ive seen a question like this, I have been looking for similar questions in google but havent been able to find anything. Any help in how to complete the question would be appreciated.

Consider a finite state machine $Μ$ with 1-bit output. The output is given by the following logic equations. Show the state transition table of $M$ with the minimum number of states. In the following equations, $I(t)$ and $O(t)$ denote the values of the input and the output at time t, respectively.

- $O(0) = 0$
- $O(1) = I(0) \cdot I(1)$
- $O(t) = I(t) \cdot I(t-1) + I(t) \cdot I(t-2) + I(t-1) \cdot I(t-2),   $where $   t \geq 2$

Comment: Shouldn't be $O(0)$ and $O(1)$ in the first and second equation, respectively?

Comment: May I ask you the origin of this exercise?

Comment: its an entrance exam that i took and subsequently failed, there was no previous mention of this type of question being on the test =/

Answer (score 1):

Interesting exercise. I will give a full answer later on, but here is a hint. The output of your machine can be computed as follows: given a sequence of bits $b_0b_1 \dotsm b_n$, add two $0$ in the front to get $00b_0b_1 \dotsm b_n$, then read this new sequence by blocks of three bits and output the majority of each block. Thus you output successively the majority of the blocks $00b_0$, $0b_0b_1$, $b_0b_1b_2$, $b_1b_2b_3$, etc. The majority of a block is $1$ if at least two bits are equal to $1$ and is $0$ otherwise. Now, a machine with $4$ states suffices to compute this function.

**Update**. Here is the sequential automaton:
[image]

Some details. The input is in red, the output in blue and the vertical bar is a separator. Next, if $b_t, b_{t-1}, b_{t-2}$ are bits, then $b_t⋅b_{t-1} + b_t⋅b_{t_2} + b_{t-1}⋅b_{t-2}$ is equal to the majority of $b_t, b_{t-1}, b_{t-2}$. The states represent the first two bits of a block of three and the transitions are given by 
$$\large
 (b_{t-2}b_{t-1}) \xrightarrow{\color{red}{b_t} \mid \color{blue}{MAJ(b_t, b_{t-1}, b_{t-2})}} (b_{t-1}b_t)
$$

Comment: thank you for your answer, I dont understand it completely yet but ill have more time to sit down and go through it in more detail after work.

Comment: sorry for the late reply ive been really busy with work and havent had much free time (and forgot =\). I can understand how to read the diagram but am still having trouble understanding how to get the table or diagram from the transition equation given. Looking at the third equation it seems as though its $x \cdot y \cdot z$ if two of those are 1 then the output should be 1 otherwise it is 0. when i have an input either 0 or 1 does it shift the leftmost bit out of the equation ? or is it still considered